# automation of ubuntu terminal and commands using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Can someone give me a code where I can automate.

1. Open the linux terminal using Ctrl+ALT+T.
2. Run small terminal commands using python and selenium .

I am a beginner and I want to know If i can do the above things using automation or Is there another way?

Comment: Yes you can automate that, but first you need to try out something from your end.

Comment: Create a bash file and execute it with python. You don't need selenium at all - selenium is for browsers not the OS.

Comment: Can you add some more context? I suspect there is easier way to achieve your goal.. Basically to make Selenium work with Linux UI you have to find corresponding WebDriver implementation..

Comment: i want to run few terminal commands ,it need not be linux terminal,also I am working with selenium and python so my work includes ,creating an account and run some commands in terminal for it work.I want to know how do I do that?

Comment: I have another question as well.
In front -end QA ,If i have to find the account I created using automation ,How do i do that?